# M.2 drive doesn't show up in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios

Recently updated my PC with a [Gigabyte Aorus Pro](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/sp#sp) motherboard  and updated bios to latest version (F10), I installed Windows 10 Home 64bit on the M.2 drive (SAMSUNG 950 PRO M.2 2280).

Every time I turn my PC on I get this error message 0xc0000225 but after restarting once, Windows boots up normally.

When I check in the BOS/firmware setup, I don't see the M.2 drive in there.

Even after restarting from Windows error message doesn't show up, tried updating firmware for M.2 drive but that didn't help. Error message only appears when I turn on PC or when I try to use Windows recovery tool and repair startup issues.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a flaky M.2 drive to me.

Comment: @Moab No on my previous board it was working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the first boot error only when cold booting, this might be a bad connection
on the new motherboard.

You might need to complain to Gigabyte or demand a replacement.

Comment: Thanks yeah I am planning to replace it, but it's strange that this happens on both m2 slots

Comment: That connection might be common to both.

Answer (score 1):

There are two slots on each of the M.2 ports (M2M and M2A) on that board, and your 80mm drive could use either; I recommend the top port, M2A. The [manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z390-aorus-pro_wifi_1001_190708_e.pdf) illustrates this on page 5, and again on page 20.

[image: M.2 ports on motherboard]

As noted on page 20, SATA3 port 3-1 conflicts with SATA SSDs mounted in M2A, but since your Samsung driive is PCIe/NVMe, there's no conflict with installing it in M2A.  Installing ***any*** M.2 drive in M2M will interfere with SATA3 ports 3-4 and 3-5.

The bottom slot on M.2 ports is for the M.2 drive's connectors.
The top slot is for the tab on the right end of the heat sink.

If you put the heat sink tab in the bottom slot, you can scratch the M.2 connectors, causing them to fail. If the connectors are broken, there's no connection and therefore a subsequently installed drive won't show in BIOS/firmware.

If you put the M.2 drive connectors in the heat sink tab slot, there's no connection and therefore it won't show in BIOS/firmware.

Please check the M.2 drive is installed in M2A, and that it uses the bottom hole on that port, not the top hole.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer,
At first my m2 was connected to M2M slot and had same issue, I have two other drives connected to SATA 0 and 1. Then moved it to M2A slot and still having same issue as before.